# Function return zero

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have array where each elements it's structure with name and integer value.

```
struct variable_table_element
    {
        char    name[VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE];
        int     value1;
    };
```

In addition to it, I create two functions. First fill one of table's element. Second, by name, search element of array and return it's value.

First:

```
void add_element_to_table(char input_name[VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE], int input_value)
    {
        variable_table[amount_of_full_table_element].value1 = input_value;

        for (int x = 0 ; x < VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE; x++) 
        {
            variable_table[amount_of_full_table_element].name[x] = input_name[x];
        }   


    }
```

Second:

```
int return_element_from_table(char input_name[VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE])
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < amount_of_full_table_element; x++)
        {
            if (variable_table[x].name == input_name)
            {
                return variable_table[x].value1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I do this in main():

```
add_element_to_table("name222",4);
int rw = return_element_from_table("name222");
```

In this situation rw's value is 0.

Comment: Your function doesn't return a value (formally) if the element is not found in the table.  If you use that (e.g. print it), you get undefined behaviour, which means both compilers are producing a correct result.  As already noted, your string comparison is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistake in your string comparison.You have to change

```
 if (variable_table[x].name == input_name)
```

To :-

```
 if (strcmp(variable_table[x].name, input_name)==0)
```

In C string You can't *(usefully)* compare strings using  `==`, you need to use `strcmp()`.

Also you forget to **increment** the value of **amount_of_full_table_element**. So this for loop `for (int x = 0; x < amount_of_full_table_element; x++)` always fails. You need to increment value of `amount_of_full_table_element` in function `add_element_to_table()`.

Try this modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE 30
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 60
#define NUMBER_OF_VARIABLES 30

//structure of element of table
struct variable_table_element
{
    char name[VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE];
    int value1;
};

//global variabels
struct variable_table_element variable_table[NUMBER_OF_VARIABLES];
int amount_of_full_table_element = 0;

// add integer to table
void add_element_to_table(char input_name[VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE], int input_value)
{
    variable_table[amount_of_full_table_element].value1 = input_value;

    for (int x = 0; x < VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE; x++)
        variable_table[amount_of_full_table_element].name[x] = input_name[x];
    amount_of_full_table_element++; // increment amount_of_full_table_elemen
}

int return_element_from_table(char input_name[VARIABLE_TABLE_ELEMENT_NAME_SIZE])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < amount_of_full_table_element; x++)
    {
        if (strcmp(variable_table[x].name, input_name) == 0) // string comparison in c
        {
            return variable_table[x].value1;
        }
    }
    return 0; // default return
}

int main()
{
    add_element_to_table("name222", 4);

    int rw = return_element_from_table("name222");

    printf("%i \n", variable_table[0].value1);
    printf("%i", rw);
    return 0;                                    // main needs a return 0
}
```

Also you forget to provide a default `return` type to function `return_element_from_table()` and `return 0` for `main()`.